# Issue while using protobuf-net serializer for WCF

Tags: wcf, protobuf-net

We are using protobuf-net to serialize my WCF data contract. While serializing I am getting error "Duplicate tag 9 detected in FingerPrint" any suggestion?

I am not using any attribute like `[ProtoContract]`, `[ProtoInclude]` or `[Protomember`; I am using `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` on my class.

Comment: What does FingerPrint look like?

Answer (score 0):

protobuf-net will (in the lack of something more explicit) use the Order from any [DataMember] attributes; so - are there any marked 9? How many? Each identifier must be unique per-type in protobuf-net.

Can you add a [ProtoMember] to give it a new identifier? If the file is code-generated, you can also have a partial class with [ProtoPartialMember] against the **type** (not the member), to achieve the same thing.

Comment: I have only one property in the class whose order is 9.Order of FingerPrint property is 41.I have added [ProtoMember] attribute on all member  of that particular class.But still getting same error.When i serialize the same using DataContractSerilizer then its working fine.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Output of DataContractSerilizer  is :-<Claim z:Id="i1">
<SalvageStatus/>
<ClaimId>0</ClaimId>
<CheckApproved>true</CheckApproved>
<Holds/>
<NoEnrollment>false</NoEnrollment>
<Peril i:nil="true"/>
<ClaimType i:nil="true"/>
<EndCallDetails i:nil="true"/>
<CheckDisclaimed>false</CheckDisclaimed>
<LastModifiedBy i:nil="true"/>
<CallInformations i:nil="true"/>
<FingerPrint i:nil="true"/>
</Claim>

Comment: @vivek I can't repro from that, I'm afraid. If you can post (or send me directly - see profile) something I can use to repro, I can probably find the cause (I should note, I'm the author of that library)

Answer (score 0):

ohh gr8 thanks for replying i figure out the issue why that happened.
My classes contain one or more property (data member) with same order i.e order =9 that why i was getting that error. Now i am able to serialize and deserialize my classes let you know if i will face any other issue.It would be great if you tell me the limitation of the protobuf.net.

I am planning to replace all the serializer with this one.One more thing i want to add this serializer(protobuf.net) is 10 times faster then BinarySearilizer (As per my test app) Thanks one again.

Comment: The first line is pretty much everything I already said ;p And to quote: "I have only one property in the class whose order is 9". Limitations? Works on *trees*, not *graphs* (which is common - XmlSerializer, JavaScriptSerializer and DataContractSerializer [by default] are all tree serializers); doesn't work well if all you know is that your type is `object`... and it isn't a friend of "MEX", but otherwise it rocks ;p

Comment: Thanks for replying.Now i am getting another error "No suitable Default RuleSet encoding found."  We are using System.Workflow.Activities.Rules.RuleSet as a property of a class while serialization getting the above error.Even i am not able to serialize this using Datacontract serializer only NetDataContractSerializer can serialize.What i need to do for serialize using ProtoBuf ?

Comment: I didn't see your last comment - I don't get notifications unless you include @Marc in the text; `RuleSet` probably isn't *designed* to be serialized by a contract-based serializer (`NetDataContractSerializer` is a field-based serializer, which is different). Normally I would recommend replacing (at the point of serialization) the `RuleSet` with a suitable DTO. However, it is hard to tell without more familiarity with WF.